# Is inRiver PIM has 'unit of measure' feature?

Tags: mdm, pim

I'm learning PIM tool inRiver. As per the requirement i need to display value with unit. (say 23.5 mm). I've seen in inRiver wiki that we can use units in specification entity type. My question is how can i achieve '23.5 mm' requirement in inRiver that is in 'Product entity'. Is there any server settings available for this? If anyone knows plz respond.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

inRiver has Unit of Measurement in specification templates, not on regular modelfields. You can add the UOM in the field description or (better) in the field label/name. And ofcourse, choose the right fieldtype (decimal).

Answer (score 0):

you could try to use Unit of Measurement as a custom setting in the fields, if u will be feeding it to other system, or just mention it in the name of the field if u have it just for info.

For example:

Field Type Id: ProductStorageInGb
Name: Storage [gb]